# How to use relationships in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am new to `SQLAlchemy` and I am having troubles implementing the concept of relationships into my logic.

I have two tables: `Offices` and `Departments` where departments include the office it exists in.

I tried to apply the information present in the documentation https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy_orm_building_relationship.htm but I am having struggles understanding where should I insert the `Relationship` and if `back_populates` attribute is actually useful in this case.

```
class Offices(Base):
    __tablename__: 'offices'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    code = Column(String)
    reader = Column(Integer) 


class Departments(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'departments'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    office_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('offices.id'))
    office = relationship("Offices", back_populates="departments")
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Also, will I have to define anything related to the `office` in the `department`'s `__init__` in order to save it when I try inserting new rows into the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify them `relationship` in both models

```
class Offices(Base):
    __tablename__: 'offices'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    code = Column(String)
    reader = Column(Integer) 

    departments = relationship("Departments", back_populates='office')


class Departments(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'departments'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    office_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('offices.id'))

    office = relationship("Offices", back_populates="departments")
```

After that you can achieve this (assume `department` and `office` are objects)

```
department.offices  # this will refer to office
office.departments  # this will refer to departments set (department is one of them)
```

The alternative is `backref`. It will create reverse relationship by itself, so

```
class Offices(Base):
        __tablename__: 'offices'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String)
        code = Column(String)
        reader = Column(Integer) 

    
    
    
    class Departments(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'departments'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String)
        office_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('offices.id'))

        office = relationship("Offices", backref="departments")
```

will do the same the first does